# Where is Netbeans installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I installed Netbeans on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine. I used the combined method, so Netbeans and JDK are installed from a [single file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html). However, now that it's installed I can't figure out how to start Netbeans. If I try to reinstall it says that Netbeans is already installed, but if I look in `/usr/share/netbeans` there are the installation files but nothing else. How do I run Netbeans?

Comment: What is `Logitech`?

Comment: I tried editing this, but I couldn't figure out your second paragraph at all

Answer (score 16):

Look for it:

```
sudo find / -name netbeans 2> /dev/null
```

If you get a location, it's installed. If not, I would suggest trying to use `apt` to install instead of the one-file method.

Comment: You made my day.

Answer (score 10):

looks like the netbeans installer forgot to add a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/bin/netbeans /usr/local/bin/netbeans
```

It would have made life easier for users if the install script did this.

(don't forget to update symlink when you upgrade netbeans version)

Answer (score 1):

Java before Netbeans...

```
#!/bin/sh

#Delete the line below if you only want the "open" JDK & JRE
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre;

#Makes the /usr/lib/jvm in case...
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

#Clean out /tmp...
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
cd /tmp

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.tar.gz;
tar -xvf ./*gz;

#Move it to where it can be found...
sudo mv /tmp/jdk1.7.* /usr/lib/jvm/;

#Add the new Java to the bin 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/bin/java 3;

#User chooses
sudo update-alternatives --config java;

exit 0;
```

Netbeans...

```
#!/bin/sh
# @author Yucca Nel
# Update as needed for newer Netbeans releases :D

#!/bin/sh

#Clean out /tmp...
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*;
cd /tmp;

# Update this line to reflect newer versions of Netbeans or replace 
# 'javase with 'javaee' or add jee manually via Netbeans 'plugins as needed.
wget http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0.1/final/bundles/netbeans-7.0.1-ml-javase-linux.sh;
sh /tmp/*sh;

# Add Netbeans launcher to your PATH. Doing so allows you to run 
# 'netbeans' command from the terminal
sudo ln -s ~/netbeans-7.0.1/bin/netbeans /usr/local/bin/;

# If you use VirtualBox , you can share your projects between 
# Host and guest. Name of shared folder must match 'NetBeansProjects' 
# Remove this if you don't need...
sudo mkdir ~/NetBeansProjects;
sudo mount -t vboxsf NetBeansProjects ~/NetBeansProjects;
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/local/netbeansx.x/bin
./netbeans
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle had stop supporting netbeans and this project is being taken by Apache.
Executive which command to locate where is netbeans installed on your system.

```
which netbeans
```

this would give path

```
/usr/bin/netbeans
```

If you now open this file in some editor or just cat the output of this file.

```
cat /usr/bin/netbeans
```

this would show that (as of today) apache netbeans is installed in

```
/usr/lib/apache-netbeans/
```

whereas the config files are in

```
/home/$USER/.netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running Unity in 11.10 by default, if you press the <kbd>Meta</kbd> (windows key), and type in `netbeans`,

You should be able to see few entries related to netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

you use the `which` command to find out location of any application (binary) installed.

e.g.

```
$which netbeans
```